# h5py: Correct way to slice array datasets

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I'm a bit confused here:

As far as I have understood, h5py's `.value` method reads an entire dataset and dumps it into an array, which is slow and discouraged (and should be generally replaced by `[()]`. The correct way is to use numpy-esque slicing.

However, I'm getting irritating results (with h5py 2.2.1):

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
>>> file = h5py.File("test.hdf5",'w')
# Just fill a test file with a numpy array test dataset
>>> file["test"] = np.arange(0,300000)

# This is TERRIBLY slow?!
>>> file["test"][range(0,300000)]
array([     0,      1,      2, ..., 299997, 299998, 299999])
# This is fast
>>> file["test"].value[range(0,300000)]
array([     0,      1,      2, ..., 299997, 299998, 299999])
# This is also fast
>>> file["test"].value[np.arange(0,300000)]
array([     0,      1,      2, ..., 299997, 299998, 299999])
# This crashes
>>> file["test"][np.arange(0,300000)]
```

I guess that my dataset is so small that `.value` doesn't hinder performance significantly, but how can the first option be that slow?
What is the preferred version here?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
It seems that I wasn't clear enough, sorry. I do know that `.value` copies the whole dataset into memory while slicing only retrieves the appropiate subpart. What I'm wondering is why slicing in file is *slower* than copying the whole array and then slicing in memory.
I always thought hdf5/h5py was implemented specifically so that slicing subparts would always be the fastest.

Comment: Note that `Dataset.value` property was removed in h5py 3.0. (For reference, the current h5py release in 2023 is 3.10). Use `ds[()]` to read all data from any dataset to a NumPy array. Or simply use `ds` to create a dataset object that behaves like a NumPy array.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For fast slicing with h5py, stick to the "plain-vanilla" slice notation:

```
file['test'][0:300000]
```

or, for example, reading every other element:

```
file['test'][0:300000:2]
```

Simple slicing (slice objects and single integer indices) should be very fast, as it translates directly into HDF5 hyperslab selections.

The expression `file['test'][range(300000)]` invokes h5py's version of "fancy indexing", namely, indexing via an explicit list of indices.  There's no native way to do this in HDF5, so h5py implements a (slower) method in Python, which unfortunately has abysmal performance when the lists are > 1000 elements.  Likewise for `file['test'][np.arange(300000)]`, which is interpreted in the same way.

See also:

[1] http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#fancy-indexing

[2] https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/293

Comment: The expression file['test'][range(300000)] invokes h5py's version of "fancy indexing" <- That's it! I didn't expect h5py to do that given that it's a range, but it does make sense. And thanks for the links, they're useful.

Comment: thank you for that 'fancy-indexing' link, I wanted to grab individual elements from the array and that link showed me how to do that =)

Answer (score 4):

The `.value` method is copying the data to memory as a numpy array. Try comparing `type(file["test"])` with `type(file["test"].value)`: the former should be an HDF5 dataset, the latter a numpy array.

I'm not familiar enough with the h5py or HDF5 internals to tell you exactly why certain dataset operations are slow; but the reason those two are *different* is that in one case you're slicing a numpy array in memory, and in the other slicing an HDF5 dataset from disk.

Comment: The performance of slicing in memory vs. slicing in file depends on a lot of things, including the speed of your disk and the file system overhead. It's possible that flushing 300,000 transactions incurs more overhead than just reading the whole array in, much the same way that using tar to copy an archive of 300,000 tiny files would speed things up.

Comment: I've fiddled around a little, and I get faster performance if I read *one* row from the file than if I load the entire array. That is, `file["test"][100]` is faster than `file["test"].value`.

It looks like h5py isn't implemented to convert indexing this way into slicing, even in your case where it's equivalent to `Slice(None)`. Now that I think of it, I had to manually convert array indices to `Slice` objects once to speed up an HDF5 read.

Comment: Was the Slice approach significantly faster than array indices?

Comment: Yes, provided that it's a contiguous slice like `Slice(140, 300)`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the title of your post, the 'correct' way to slice array datasets is to use the builtin slice notation

All of your answers would be equivalent to 
file["test"][:]

[:] selects all elements in the array

More information about slicing notation can be found here, 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

I use hdf5 + python often, I've never had to use the .value methods. When you access a dataset in an array like such as
myarr = file["test"]

python copies the dataset in the hdf5 into an array for you already.