# Why is it faster to read whole hdf5 dataset than a slice

Tags: python, io, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to figure out why this happens:

```
In [1]: import time, h5py as h5
In [2]: f = h5.File('myfile.hdf5', 'r')                                                                                                                                    
In [3]: st = time.time(); data = f["data"].value[0,:,1,...]; elapsed = time.time() - st;
In [4]: elapsed
Out[4]: 11.127676010131836
In [5]: st = time.time(); data = f["data"][0,:,1,...]; elapsed2 = time.time() - st;
In [6]: elapsed2
Out[6]: 59.810582399368286
In [7]: f["data"].shape
Out[7]: (1, 4096, 6, 16, 16, 16, 16)
In [8]: f["data"].chunks
Out[8]: (1, 4096, 1, 16, 16, 16, 16)
```

As you can see, loading the whole dataset into memory and then taking a slice is faster than taking that same slice from the dataset.

The chunk size matches the slice, so it should all be contiguous memory, right? Why then is it so much slower?

The dataset is compressed with gzip (`opts=2`).

Following Andrew's comment, I run it clearing the caches between both reads:

```
elapsed1: 11.001180410385132
elapsed2: 43.19723725318909
48.61user 4.45system 0:54.65elapsed 97%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 8431596maxresident)k
479584inputs+0outputs (106major+3764414minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

(This next run had a 10 second delay between the two reads to clear the caches)

```
elapsed1: 11.46790862083435
elapsed2: 43.438515186309814

48.54user 4.66system 1:05.71elapsed 80%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 8431944maxresident)k
732504inputs+0outputs (220major+3764449minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: What's your OS?  If it's on Linux, try running the different versions of your Python code under `/usr/bin/time /your/python/here`.  That will show where the CPU time is spent - kernel/system or user-space, and provide some clue as to what's going on.  Also on Linux, you can use `strace` to see what system calls are made in both versions.  I suspect the "read it all into memory" unzips the data only once, while the slower method has to seek and unzip multiple times.

Comment: Also, if you're on LInux, [flush your page cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system) before running each of your different versions

Comment: You are using fancy slicing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405220/4045774 I mentioned this case in the "simplest form of fancy indexing ". Your chunks are also extremely large. This isn't realy necessary if you use a proper chunk-cache size.

Comment: There are also much faster compression algorithms available than gzip. If portability between between multiple languages (gzip comes with every HDF5 installation, unlike the much faster blosc) isn't an issue, consider blosc. If your data offers a high compression ratio and stored on a HDD, it is often faster than a uncompressed dataset. eg. 900MB/s from a HDD -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/48997927/4045774

Comment: I wonder how `data[0][:,1]` does.

Answer (score 1):

First I ran a test of my own. I don't have your HDF5 file, so using one of my test files. My test Table dataset has ~54,000 rows (which seems larger than yours).
Timing result with .value[] gives

```
>>> elapsed
0.15540122985839844
```

Timing result with NumPy indexing gives:

```
>>> elapsed2
0.12980079650878906
```

So, I don't see much difference in performance. Maybe it's related to the dataset sizes we are testing, or complexity of data tables?

A little reading of the the most recent h5py documentation has some interesting comments about `Dataset.value` (from Release 2.8.0 - Jun 05, 2018; emphasis mine):
**Dataset.value property is now deprecated.**
The property `Dataset.value`, which dates back to h5py 1.0, is deprecated and will be removed in a later release.
***This property dumps the entire dataset into a NumPy array.*** Code using `.value` should be updated to use NumPy indexing, using `mydataset[...]` or `mydataset[()]` as appropriate.

Your timing tests seem to be counter to the highlighted observation above.

I think you need to ask a h5py developer to comment on the performance differences (and where data is stored -- in memory vs on disk). Have you checked with the [h5py user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/h5py)?

**Edit:**
After posting, I found this SO Q&A. It has lots of good comments and includes responses from the h5py developer:
[h5py: Correct way to slice array datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766145/h5py-correct-way-to-slice-array-datasets)

Comment: OP's matrix has over 1 billion elements.