# h5py: how to stack multiple HDF5 datasets to a single np.array

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I have a 50GB h5 file which only has datasets and has circa 7m x 256d numpy arrays a values.

I want to generate a slice of it since the whole file cant be loaded to memory but I am struggling to do this.

so, I have:

```
    f=h5py.File("./somefile.h5","r",libver='latest')
    keys_=list(f.keys()) # works - I get all the keys and check the length and it ads up.
    print(f[:5]) # fails saying it need a string for dataset name
    print(f[()][:5]) # fails same as above
    print(f['.'][:5]) #fails
```

this is driving me mad!

To reiterate, there are no groups, just datasets - how do I get slices say for example 1m slices?

Comment: groups or not, datasets are referenced one at a time by name.  In other words use one of the `keys_`. You can 'slice' a dataset, but can't 'slice' several at once.

Comment: @hpaulj so there is no chance of chunking it somehow?

Comment: `h5py` has some `keys` walking functions, but I haven't used them much.

Comment: What exactly do you want with your `f[:5]`? The first 5 elements of all datasets? Or all data from the first 5 datasets? Something else?

Comment: @Homer512 I would like the first 5 datasets :(

Comment: @Homer512 as in all the data from the first 5 datasets. I am essentially training a neural net and I would like the data in slices/chunks... <-- thats the context of my question. I naively thought I can just slice it this way `f[:5]`.. I am now wondering if I put all the datasets into a group and then do `f["foo"][:5]`.. will this work?

Comment: Even if you have a group you can't access datasets by number or slice.  Go back and reread the h5py docs.

Comment: @hpaulj are you sure? I see here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766145/h5py-correct-way-to-slice-array-datasets how are they slicing it then

Comment: In the answer you linked they access `file['test'][0:300000]`. `test` is a dataset. They access that dataset alone. HDF5, same as groups inside them, act like python dictionaries that map dataset and group names (strings) to dataset and group objects. The datasets themselves act like numpy arrays and can be sliced. Python dictionaries cannot be sliced

Comment: It sounds as if you have control over your data structure. If all datasets have the same shape and data type (which would be a prerequisite for slicing as you want it), then why don't you put all the data into one huge dataset? That can be sliced like you want it

Comment: @Homer512 yea this is what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading your question, I realize you want to STACK datasets into a single array (e.g., not SLICE a dataset). I have updated my answer to show how to do this.

First, you don't need groups to access datasets. You simply specify the dataset name in the H5 object path.

Also, your code don't call `f.close()`. This can cause problems if you accidentally exit the program with the file open. It's better to use Python's file context manager (`with/as:`). That way the file is closed when it exits the `with/as:` block.

**How to stack datasets as np.array slices:**
This procedure is similar to the original answer. However, it creates an empty NumPy array large enough to hold the data before it loops over the datasets. This process assumes the all datasets have the same shape (and dtype). Since I don't know your dataset shape, I made it a variable and the last index of the array is the dataset index. Also, there a tests to be sure each dataset matches the shape and dtype of the target array.

Code to stack datasets below:

```
with h5py.File("./somefile.h5","r") as f:
    ds_names = list(f.keys())
    n_slices = 5
    ds_shape = f[ds_names[0]].shape
    arr_shape =  ds_shape + (n_slices,)
    ds_arr = np.zeros(arr_shape,dtype=f[ds_names[0]].dtype)
    print(f'array; Type: {ds_arr.dtype}, Shape: {ds_arr.shape}')
    print(f'{ds_arr.shape[:-1]}')
    
    for cnt,ds in enumerate(ds_names[:n_slices]):
        if isinstance(f[ds], h5py.Dataset) and \
           f[ds].shape == ds_arr.shape[:-1] and and f[ds].dtype == ds_arr.dtype:
            print(f'For dataset {ds}; Type: {f[ds].dtype}, Shape: {f[ds].shape}')
            ds_arr[...,cnt] = f[ds][()]
```

**Original answer to slice datasets**
No, for those that might want to slice a dataset, slicing syntax is identical to NumPy syntax. So, if you have multiple axes (dimensions) you will need to specify slice size for each dimension.

Code below will access your file, loop over all root level objects (keys), print dataset info, and attempt to read a slice. This assumes the slice syntax is appropriate for your dataset. I added logic to test that each object is a dataset.

```
with h5py.File("./somefile.h5","r") as f:
    for ds in f:
        if isinstance(f[ds], h5py.Dataset):
            print(f'For dataset {ds}; Type: {f[ds].dtype}, Shape: {f[ds].shape}')
            print(f[ds][:5]) # gets a small slice assuming slice syntax is correct
```

Comment: Thank you - yea you are right (I realised your points after experimenting with the h5 files). Essentially you can slice a dataset but not all the datasets